# ReverseCompositeView missing from mvp4g jar files?

Tags: gwt, mvp4g

I am trying to use mvp4g for gwt, and in the sample tutorial (http://mvp4g.blogspot.com/2011/04/mvp-pattern-associated-with-event-bus.html) they have the following code for building the view:

```
public class MenuView extends ReverseCompositeView<IMenuPresenter> implements IMenuView {
...

}
```

Is this something that other people have found missing from the JAR files? Is there an easy way to get this somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to other people and I guess its missing from the JAR file. I ended up getting a code snippet from them they found online and just created a class in my project for it using the following code:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.mvp4g.client.view.ReverseViewInterface;

public class ReverseCompositeView<P> extends Composite implements ReverseViewInterface<P> {

protected P presenter;

 @Override
 public void setPresenter( P presenter ) {
 this.presenter = presenter;
 }

 @Override
 public P getPresenter() {
  return presenter;
 }

}
```